# How to find linear regression between groups using data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, regression

I am trying to find the linear regression between all available groups of the following dataset.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(time = c(rep(rep(1:100, times = 1), 4), rep(1:30, times = 1)),
                   group = c(rep(c("a","b","c","d"), each = 100), rep("e", 30)), 
                   value = rnorm(430))
dt[]
      time group      value
  1:    1     a  0.1625954
  2:    2     a -1.2288462
  3:    3     a -0.1628570
  4:    4     a  1.0597886
  5:    5     a -1.1828334
 ---                      
426:   26     e -1.3762654
427:   27     e  0.3761436
428:   28     e -1.6982330
429:   29     e  0.1940263
430:   30     e -0.4631258
```

The output should be something like

```
group1     group2      regression
a           b           1.2
a           c           0.3
b           c           0.5
d           a           4.3
...
```

I am looking for a solution using data.table library only.

1. Linear regression of all the combinations of groups should be found. That includes cases `a~b` and `b~a` as the regression for each of these cases will be different.
2. Since the size of some groups is different, the time variables should be used to find the common rows between any set of groups.
3. The solution will require finding all combinations of groups.

Comment: I guess you are looking for only a, b and not b, a right?

Comment: I am looking for both (a,b) and (b,a), as regression of each will give different results.

Comment: One more thing, the size of these groups might be different. The data.table will be like - ```dt <- data.table(group = c(rep(1:4, 100), rep(5, 30)), a = rnorm(430))
```

Comment: wouldn't that create a length difference with regression

Comment: Can you show your code for a single case with different length

Comment: I have added a variable called ```time``` in the dataset, and while calculating linear regression, a subset with common time should be considered.

Comment: Since the number of groups is large in the original dataset, I don't want to use ```split``` function to make subsets of data as that will slow the execution considerably.

Comment: `split` is faster than `==`

Comment: WIth lots of groups, may be consider using parallel with `foreach`

Comment: oh...ok, I did not know that. I will use ```mcapply``` to solve the problem of a large number of groups. I have updated the dataset to make groups alphabetical.

Comment: that wouldn't matter for the code

Comment: Here is what I came up with `lst1 <- split(dt, dt$group)
rbindlist(combn(names(lst1), 2, FUN = function(x) {s1 <- lst1[[x[1]]]; s2 <- lst1[[x[2]]]; i1 <- intersect(s1$time, s2$time); if(length(i1) > 0) na.omit(s1[s2, on = .(time)][, . (group1 = first(s1$group), group2 = first(s2$group), regression = lm(i.value ~ value)$coef[2])]) else data.table(group1 = first(s1$group), group2 = first(s2$group), regression = NA_real_)}, simplify = FALSE))`

Comment: It is based on split, so it may not be optimal for you

Comment: Thanks @Arun for handling the case where ```li <  0```, Please post this answer.

Comment: I think you can use `future.apply` to loop in parallel or `foreach`.  - `foreach` is very fast in my experience

Comment: Sure thing, I will try ```foreach```. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new data, we could `split` the data by 'group' into a `list`.  Then, use `combn` on the `names` of the `list` for pairwise combination, extract the `list` elements (`s1`, `s2`),  check if there are `any` common 'time' (`intersect`).  Use a condition based on `length` i.e. if there are common elements, then apply the `lm` on the corresponding 'value' columns, create a data.table with summarised `coef` along with the group names and `rbind` the `list` elements

```
library(data.table)
lst1 <- split(dt, dt$group)
rbindlist(combn(names(lst1), 2, FUN = function(x) {
      s1 <- lst1[[x[1]]]
      s2 <- lst1[[x[2]]]
      i1 <- intersect(s1$time, s2$time)
      if(length(i1) > 0) na.omit(s1[s2, on = .(time)][, 
        . (group1 = first(s1$group), group2 = first(s2$group), 
          regression = lm(i.value ~ value)$coef[2])]) 
       else
         data.table(group1 = first(s1$group), group2 = first(s2$group), 
         regression = NA_real_)}, simplify = FALSE))
```

-output

```
     group1 group2  regression
 1:      a      b  0.03033996
 2:      a      c  0.06391242
 3:      a      d -0.09138112
 4:      a      e -0.27738183
 5:      b      c  0.05663270
 6:      b      d  0.05481604
 7:      b      e  0.27789495
 8:      c      d -0.13987978
 9:      c      e  0.16388299
10:      d      e  0.12380720
```

---

If we want full combinations, use either `expand.grid` or `CJ` (from `data.table`

```
dt2 <- CJ(group1 = names(lst1), group2 = names(lst1))[group1 != group2]
dt2[, rbindlist(Map(function(x, y) {
       s1 <- lst1[[x]]
       s2 <- lst1[[y]]
       i1 <- intersect(s1$time, s2$time)
       if(length(i1) > 0) na.omit(s1[s2, on = .(time)][,
           data.table(group1 = x, group2 = y, 
          regresion = lm(i.value ~ value)$coef[2])]) else 
           data.table(group1 = x, group2 = y, regression = NA_real_)

        }, group1, group2))]
```

-output

```
  group1 group2   regresion
 1:      a      b  0.03033996
 2:      a      c  0.06391242
 3:      a      d -0.09138112
 4:      a      e -0.27738183
 5:      b      a  0.03247826
 6:      b      c  0.05663270
 7:      b      d  0.05481604
 8:      b      e  0.27789495
 9:      c      a  0.07488082
10:      c      b  0.06198333
11:      c      d -0.13987978
12:      c      e  0.16388299
13:      d      a -0.09295215
14:      d      b  0.05208743
15:      d      c -0.12144302
16:      d      e  0.12380720
17:      e      a -0.25136439
18:      e      b  0.34052322
19:      e      c  0.28677255
20:      e      d  0.21435666
```

Comment: Thanks @Arun! It does handle cases such as ```a~b```, but the other scenario of ```b~a``` is not produced. Is it possible for you to update the code to handle ```b~a``` scenario?

Comment: @Saurabh For that, we need `expand.grid` or `CJ`, and then remove the ones that are same

Comment: Okay, I will try to do that. Thanks!

Comment: @Saurabh I didn't use it earlier because you mentioned the data is really big with lots of groups

Comment: On my dataset, this code ran for 12 minutes and I needed to abort it. I will try to make it faster using ```foreach```, then I will handle the ```CJ``` part.

Comment: @Saurabh I added the CJ part

Comment: Thanks @Arun for the brilliant answer.